# asp.net Column Chart is not aligning with the custom label and it does not display spaces between columns

Tags: charts

I am trying to generate a chart to look this one
[image]

I am almost there but there are couple of issue that i can't solve.
The columns are being displayed with out a space separation between them! also the custom label that is at the very bottom is not aligning up with each column!

this is the output the i get out of my existing code

[image]

so
1) I need to spread the columns across the x axis
2) align the custom label to each column!

I appreciate any help or feedback on this problem

this is the code that generates the current image. Please keep in mind the my dataset "ds" have values like this

Emerging 28.45646456
Dent 14.1456465
Audio 27.456456
Cosmetic 43.44564456
Vet 35.15465646645

public void GenerateChart(){

```
    //ds is generated and has values

    Chart2.Series.Clear();
    Chart2.Legends.Clear();
    Chart2.Titles.Clear();


    //if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RunOnLocalhost"] == "True") {
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower() == "localhost"){
        Chart2.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
    }


    Chart2.Width = 1000;
    Chart2.Height = 700;
    Chart2.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
    Chart2.Titles.Add("Usage Impact By Industry");
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "(%) Usage Lift";
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
    Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = -5;


    string tmp = "";
    string sName = "";
    double percentage = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int x = 1;
    double index = 0.1;
    foreach (DataRow Row in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

        if (tmp != Row["Industry"].ToString()) {

            sName = Row["Industry"].ToString();
            Chart2.Series.Add(sName);
            Chart2.Legends.Add(sName).DockedToChartArea = "ChartArea1";

            i++;
        }

        if (Convert.ToDouble(Row["B4"]) > 0) {
            percentage = (Convert.ToDouble(Row["After4"]) - Convert.ToDouble(Row["B4"])) / Convert.ToDouble(Row["B4"]) * 100;
            percentage = Math.Round(percentage, 0);
        }
        else {

            percentage = 0;
        }


        Chart2.Series[sName].Points.AddXY(Row["Industry"].ToString(), percentage);
        Chart2.Series[sName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        Chart2.Series[sName]["PointWidth"] = ".5";
        Chart2.Series[sName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart2.Series[sName].LabelFormat = percentage + "%";

        CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel();

        label.FromPosition = 0 + index;
        label.ToPosition = .01 + index;
        label.Text = Row["Industry"].ToString();
        label.RowIndex = 0;

        Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(label);


        x++;
        index += 0.2;
        tmp = Row["Industry"].ToString();
  }



}
```

Comment: any help guys. I will appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you took the different series for the X-Axis. Take a single series in your chart like,

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
<Series>
         <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueType="Auto" YValueType="Int32">
         </asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
         <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">                                
         </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Here I have taken "Series1" in chart.

Now replace your "sName" with "Series1"

```
Chart2.Series[sName].Points.AddXY(Row["Industry"].ToString(), percentage);
```

to

```
Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(Row["Industry"].ToString(), percentage);
```

I think problem should be solved.